# dc.sunburst ordering pie-slices

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, sunburst-diagram

I have a question related to dc.sunburst (dc.js).

I have created one with two "layers" and I would like to order the slices (either from the first and the second layer) by ascending/descending size.

Would you have an idea to implement it ? I have tried something like:

```
sunburstChart
 .dimension(bla)
 .group(blabla)
 .ordering(function (d) {return d.value;})
```

But it actually appears like if this function does not exist.

Thanks for reply !